# Is there a way to modify this loop?

Tags: c#

So I was trying to make this code test if there are certain letters in a *user-inputted* word and determine how many of that certain letter is in that user input.

Currently I get 4 for `aCounter` and 4 for `bCounter` if I input the word `"aabb"`.

How do I make it so that for example the *loop* of testing for letter `"a"` stops if there are 2 a's and it already tested for `"a"` 2 times.

```
static int aCounter, bCounter;

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the secret word: ");
    string word = Console.ReadLine();

    for(int i = 0; word.Length > i; i++)
    {       
        if (word.Count(letter => letter == 'a') > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe word contains a");
            aCounter++;
        }

        if (word.Count(letter => letter == 'b') > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe word contains b");
            bCounter++;
        }

        if (aCounter > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aCounter);
        }

        if (bCounter > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bCounter);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are seemingly mixing *linq* with *loops*

I am guessing this is more inline with what you want (by just removing the loop)

```
Console.Write("Enter the secret word: ");
string word = Console.ReadLine();

aCounter = word.Count(letter => letter == 'a');
bCounter = word.Count(letter => letter == 'b');

if (aCounter > 0)
   Console.WriteLine($"The word contains a : {aCounter}");

if (bCounter > 0)
   Console.WriteLine($"The word contains b : {bCounter}");
```

**Output**

```
Enter the secret word: aabb
The word contains a : 2
The word contains b : 2
```

You could also count **all** the *character occurrences* and put them in a *dictionary*, then test explicitly

```
var letters = word.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

if (letters.TryGetValue('a', out var aCount))
   Console.WriteLine($"The word contains a : {aCount}");

if (letters.TryGetValue('a', out var bCount))
   Console.WriteLine($"The word contains b : {bCount}");
```